# Sitecore Reporting Web Error when using Stimulsoft Designer

Tags: sitecore, stimulsoft

I am trying to set up a report using the Stimulsoft tool for desktop to create a new report from scratch. After following the cookbook for setting these up I go to look at the report in the Engagement Analytics section of the web interface and I see this error:

> Report /sitecore/shell/Applications/Analytics/Reports/NewReport.mrt
>   cannot be rendered : System.Exception:
>   c:\Windows\Temp\t55vr4jf.0.cs(113,40) : error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name 'Sitecore' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile(String path, Stream stream,
>   StiOutputType outputType, Boolean autoCreate, Object
>   standaloneReportType) at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile(String
>   path, Stream stream, StiOutputType outputType, Boolean autoCreate) at
>   Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile(String path, StiOutputType
>   outputType, Boolean autoCreate) at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Reports.ReportFactory.CompileReport(StiReport
>   report, String reportId) at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Reports.ReportFactory.FillReport(StiReport report,
>   Database database, ID reportItemId, Nullable1 startDate, Nullable1
>   endDate, String email, IEnumerable1 filters) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.ReportRunner.ReportPage.FillReport(StiReport
>   report, IEnumerable1 filterSelection) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.ReportRunner.ReportPage.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e)

I've tried to add more references to my report using the windows interface, but some I've tried don't make any changes, while others just add more of the same error.

When I go to preview the report in the designer I get different errors:

1. Error! The error of compilation
   The error of compilation is found in the 'Report' report:
   'Reports.Report.PagesDataSoure' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'Reports.Report.PagesDataSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. Error! The error of compilation
   The error of compilation is found in the 'Report' report:
   'Reports.Report.PagesDataSoure' does not contain a definition for 'Clear' and no extension method 'Clear' accepting a first argument of type 'Reports.Report.PagesDataSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas would be totally welcome! Thanks!

Comment: I have this up on other forums as well, one suggestion I got was to check in my \temp folder of the website and delete any NewReport.dll files. I checked for this, and there were no such files.

Comment: What is in your list of DLL references for the report in the properties?